# Local css file loads, direct address fails

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML I am having problems with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://resources.8thdaystudio.com/neonlights.css" type="text/css" />
```

I have a copy of the css file in my page's local folder, and when I put neonlights.css in the href, it works. I have a copy in my resources server to use from any of my pages, but it's not applying the css when I do the direct link. Using inspect in Chrome it's not showing me an error loading the file but still not applying the css.

Comment: Where are you loading that html file? There are headers that can be sent disallowing CSS from a location that isn't the original page.

Comment: @dannystaple This is the whole header:  '<head>  <title>Big C's Pizza</title>  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://resources.8thdaystudio.com/neonlights.css" type="text/css" />  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="w3.css" />  <script src="index.js"></script>  </head>'

Comment: Simple question: Have you tried putting `http://www.`? --- and maybe get rid of the `;` behind the link?

Comment: @J.DKYSR I have tried it with the www. in there, and the ; was just a typo in my comment. It's not in my actual code.

Comment: Now inspect is showing me a problem with that line saying, "transfered with MIME type text/html"

Comment: Not quite the header I meant - however, if you've spotted the Mime type - that is also in the headers. I meant the http headers, not  the html page head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is observed that the url:
http://71.57.185.233:82/neonlights.css loads as text/css
but http://resources.8thdaystudio.com/neonlights.css loads as text/html.
It's due to your server's configuration as you indicated. I have verified this in Fiddler.

Comment: Do you think it is because resources.8thdaystudio.com is a sub-domain pointing to a different server?

Answer (score 0):

Through some reading about MIME types I figured out that the likely problem is my server. I'm running Servers Ultimate Pro on an Android device and I believe it's sending the file with the incorrect type.